# Правильно ли расставлены запятые, скобки и тире в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот

Сбежавшего во время наводнения из Тбилисского зоопарка бегемота ( испуганный и одновременно агрессивный, он долго бродил по опустевшим, покрытым огромными лужами улицам города) удалось, в конце концов, к общему удовлетворению спасателей, обездвижить метким усыпляющим выстрелом, после чего начался следующий этап спасения многотонного "питомца" - чисто технический.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно, есть только одно замечание.

"В конце концов" - обособление не требуется, это обстоятельство со значением "в завершение, напоследок, после всего", обозначает заключительный этап реального действия.

У вводного сочетания другие значения: а) выражает нетерпение; б) обозначает заключительный характер высказывания.

Правильно:

Сбежавшего во время наводнения из Тбилисского зоопарка бегемота ( испуганный и одновременно агрессивный, он долго бродил по опустевшим, покрытым огромными лужами улицам города) удалось в конце концов, к общему удовлетворению спасателей, обездвижить метким усыпляющим выстрелом, после чего начался следующий этап спасения многотонного "питомца" - чисто технический.

Comment: Вера, а разве после скобок запятая не требуется?

Comment: По-моему, пограничные знаки за скобки не выносятся.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под ''пограничные знаки''? После бегемота запятая нужна?

Comment: Вставка на знаки препинания не влияет. Получаем: Сбежавшего бегемота удалось  обездвижить. Какая здесь может быть запятая?

Comment: Я знаю, Вера. Я сомневался насчет запятой после бегемота, которая при наличии вставки должна быть поставлена после вставки. Сейчас все стало ясно.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ,  Vera!